# Deallocating linked list

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

Is this solution enough to deallocate the linked list?
How can I verify it is freeing the memory that was allocated to the list?

```
void freeList(EmpList** listHead)
{
    EmpList* iter = *listHead;
    while(iter != NULL)
    {
        iter = iter->next;
        free(*listHead);
        *listHead = iter;
    }

}
```

Here's the structs

```
typedef struct employeeData
{
    int EMP_ID;
    char name[21];
    int dept;
    int rank;
    double salary;
} Employee;

typedef struct empList
{
    Employee employee;
    struct empList* next;
} EmpList;
```

Comment: Why are you passing an `EmpList * *` (pointer to pointer) to your function?

Comment: I believe it is so that the caller can define `EmpList *head` and then have `head` automatically set to `NULL` (by calling `freeList(&head)`.)

Comment: In my implementation, and not saying i did it right so please say something if its wrong, but in order to change listHead i needed a pointer-to-pointer since im not dereferencing the data at listhead but rather the pointer pointing to the list. and what neo said

Comment: Maybe this was the intention (though I'd consider it poor style).  But `freeList` doesn't set to `NULL`.

Comment: by virtue of how the loop works it will be *listHead == NULL when the loop ends

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point.  Not sure if it is the best method to do it, but working, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *verify* that it is freeing the memory by using a memory checker like Valgrind. A memory checker will let you know at the end of your program's execution if you left any memory dangling. Additionally, Valgrind can check for a wide range of memory misuses (going off the end of an array, using deallocated memory, uninitialized memory, and many more features).

As for your implementation, it looks pretty reasonable.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into Valgrind thats useful... lol does it tell you if you forget to close files, i do that more then anything.

Comment: It does! See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html for a full list of options. The one you want is `--track-fds`.

Comment: neo ive i'm getting Invalid write/read of size 8 when running valgrind is that bad? When the program ends it says that the heap stack is 0.

Comment: Invalid writes and reads are both bad.  It likely means you are accessing memory after it has been released, which is a no-no.

Comment: 'size 8' is suspicious - you compiling 64-bit?

Comment: yeah i figured it out i was allocating sizeof(Employee) rather then sizeof(EmpList)